# Scrape password protected asp page

Tags: php, asp.net, cookies, curl, libcurl

I would like to develop automatic scraper for asp password protected web page. I have a login/password for this page.

First of all, a look in to Firebug log during authorization via firefox. What I have found:

1. When I open login page, I get cookie with "__RequestVerificationToken". i.e `http://mysite`
2. When I press Login button FF makes POST query to `http://mysite/Account/Login` with parameters UserName, Password and __RequestVerificationToken, also it uses cookie saved on step 1
3. In case of successful authorisation I get another cookie .ASPXAUTH and goes to `http://mysite/Account/Index` (page which I want to scrape)

My code

```
//1. Get __RequestVerificationToken cookie

    $urlLogin = "http://mysite";
    $cookieFile = "cookie.txt";
    $regs=array();
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen("answer.txt", "w+"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); 
    
    $data=curl_exec($ch);

//2. Parse token value for the post request

$hash=file_get_contents("answer.txt");
preg_match_all('/=(.*); p/i',$hash, $regs);

//3. Make a post request

    $postData = '__RequestVerificationToken='.$regs[1][0].'&UserName=someLogin'.'&Password=somePassword';
    $urlSecuredPage = "http://mysite/Account/Login";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlSecuredPage); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); 

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

At step 3 my cookie saved on step 1 is rewriting with new value of __RequestVerificationToken. I don`t understand why it happens. As a result I can not authorize due to wrong __RequestVerificationToken and get HTTP 500 error.

Where I`m wrong?

Comment: Your `__RequestVerificationToken` is session dependent, as far i am getting, as soon as user get authenticated, the value of `__RequestVerificationToken` gets changed, which remains valid for that user only, once user logs out, value will change again. So turn your logic based on this. I think.

Comment: saveATcode - u r right that __RequestVerificationToken is session depended, but it is still the same in FF from step 1 to step 3. It changes only if I close browser and visit site again.

Comment: At step 3 my cookie saved on step 1 is rewriting with new value of __RequestVerificationToken. You wrote this in your question, which means error is somewhere else..

Comment: Firstly, options CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR must be initialized with FULL path value. "cookie.txt" is a relative path.
Secondly, `$postData` must be url-encoded. However you don't need do it manually. You may use `http_build_query()` to build encoded POST data or immediately pass assoc. array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option.

Comment: hindmost - I use full path for cookies, just delete it in the post. And thanks for mentioning url-encoding, I forgot this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are should be two things for  __RequestVerificationToken. One of them in hidden input value, the second one in the cookie. Value from hidden input value is sent in each request. And for each request it has a new value. It depends on cookie value.

So you need to save  input value and cookie, and send them back together. If you won't send value from hidden input, then Asp.Net MVC thinks that this is an attack, and generate new cookie. New cookie will be generated only if validation failed or the cookie itself doesn't exists. If you get that cookie, and you always send __RequestVerificationToken input value with POST request, then it shouldn't generate new cookie.

If it's still generated, then you are sending incorrect __RequestVerificationToken from hidden input value. Try to do the same from Fiddler\Charles, and check will be return success result or not.

They are used to prevent CSRF attacks.

Comment: I think about it but there are no hidden input values on the page or I missed it. Page -http://www.ins-union-life.ru/

Comment: It has it - `<form action="/Account/Login" id="loginfrm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="B_6PKpmmHcanUa7JJL944Pe_vSssY7vM_-OJK5fU5EhqU5mSTjpoUfn02xTNX8DnkPsOPZn_Ybu7dv5dYJ9YKeGyyiZO8_ApIzYYhqlxXDh4S44CtJv4WdWddAemkfnjKFTYI8sZJOZ5b_eN0PVyA3D6HF5EgNfeAl2LWLew9Q01" />`

Comment: The AntiForgery validation works based on both input value and cookie value. So, if one of them are missing then it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Big thanks for [Sergey Litvinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169635/sergey-litvinov) and [hindmost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2118955/hindmost)

Correct code below

```
$urlLogin = "http://mysite";
$cookieFile = "/Volumes/Media/WebServer/aszh/cookie.txt";
$regs=array();

$ch = curl_init();

//Make GET request and get __RequestVerificationToken cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen("/Volumes/Media/WebServer/aszh/answer.txt", "w+"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); 

$data=curl_exec($ch);

//Parse answer and get __RequestVerificationToken hidden input value
preg_match_all('/type="hidden" value="(.*)" /i', $data, $regs);
$token = $regs[1][0];

$postData = array('__RequestVerificationToken'=>$token,
     'UserName'=>'userName',
     'Password'=>'password');


//Make POST request and get .ASPXAUTH cookie
$urlSecuredPage = "http://mysite/Account/Login";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlSecuredPage); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); 

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```